# Copy symbol address to symbol

Tags: cuda

I'd like to set a symbol pointer to a symbol address, from the host.  Something like:

```
__device__ float * symbolPtr;   // address of symbol[3]
__device__ float symbol[5];

cudaGetSymbolAddress( &symbolPtr, symbol[3] );
```

I've only used this to get a device address to the host.  But there is no mention that it can't set a symbol variable.

Here is another approach:

```
cudaMemcpytoSymbol(&symbolPtr, &symbol[3], sizeof(void*), 0, cudaMemcpyDeviceToDevice);
```

I doubt either of these will work.  Is there a simpler way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This method worked for me.  There may be a better way.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define N 5
#define Q 3

#define cudaCheckErrors(msg) \
    do { \
        cudaError_t __err = cudaGetLastError(); \
        if (__err != cudaSuccess) { \
            fprintf(stderr, "Fatal error: %s (%s at %s:%d)\n", \
                msg, cudaGetErrorString(__err), \
                __FILE__, __LINE__); \
            fprintf(stderr, "*** FAILED - ABORTING\n"); \
            exit(1); \
        } \
    } while (0)

__device__ float *symbolPtr;
__device__ float symbol[N];

__global__ void mykernel(){

  for (int i=0; i<N; i++)
    symbol[i] = (float) i;
  printf("symbol[%d] = %f\n", Q, *symbolPtr);

}

int main(){

  float *temp;
  cudaGetSymbolAddress((void **)&temp, symbol);
  cudaCheckErrors("cudaGetSymbolAddress fail");
  temp += Q;
  cudaMemcpyToSymbol(symbolPtr, &temp, sizeof(float *));
  cudaCheckErrors("cudaMemcpyToSymbol fail");

  mykernel<<<1,1>>>();
  cudaDeviceSynchronize();
  cudaCheckErrors("kernel fail");


  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for working this out.  I kept running into pointer issues with the original post.

Answer (score 0):

A static approach would be:

```
__device__ float symbol[5];
__device__ float * symbolPtr= &symbol[3];
```