# Removing runtime errors with the -G flag

Tags: cuda

This is a follow up Q from [cudaMemcpyToSymbol vs cudaMemcpy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15391394/cudamemcpytosymbol-vs-cudamemcpy)

I'm under the impression the -G flag is for making cudaGDB builds.  I'm seeing it clear errors as well.  (The error in the code below is intentional.  The Q is about why the return error didn't show it.)

```
__constant__ float flt[480];   // 1920 bytes
__constant__ int  ints[160];   // 640 bytes

Main() {
 float* pFlts;
 cudaMalloc((void**)&pFlts, 1920+640);

 cudaError_t eerr=cudaMemcpyToSymbol(ints,pFlts,sizeof(ints),sizeof(ints),cudaMemcpyDeviceToDevice);
 printf("ErrVal= %d\n",(int)eerr);
}
```

When I build w/: **nvcc junk.cu -o junk**, and run it w/: **./junk**, my result is: ErrVal= **11**, which is "invalid argument".

When I build w/: **nvcc junk.cu -G -o junk**, and run it w/: **./junk**, my result is: ErrVal= **0**, which is cudaSuccess.

I don't have a lot of experience w/ the -G flag, but this seems like odd behavior.
Why does -G erase return errors?

Comment: When I comment out the first line (remove flt[480]), the error stays (11) w/ and w/o the -G.  I'm thinking there is a length/size calculation issue of the symbol.  And it changes w/ the -G flag.  Can anyone else reproduce this?

Comment: I can reproduce it.  which cuda version are you using?  CUDA 5?

Comment: yes, CUDA 5.0  V0.2.1221

Comment: When I swap the order of the first 2 lines, ErrVal= 0, w/ or w/o the -G flag.  This is pretty strange.

Comment: You are again copying past the end of `ints`. Check your offset argument.

Comment: And there is no guarantee that wrong addresses or offsets will be caught.

Comment: @tera Please explain the 'no guarantee'.  It is an obvious error that should be easy to detect.  You are suggesting the range-checking is inconsistent?

Comment: I don't see this as obvious. Catching this kind of mistakes would at least require keeping range information with every symbol, something that C traditionally doesn't do. If at all, errors are mostly caught when accesses cross page borders.

Comment: My prior experience w/ Memcpy lead me to believe it performed range-checking.  (I thought it was odd to have range-checking in this operation.)  Now I'm thinking, I probably wasn't seeing a range-fault, but rather a mem access fault.  (Which makes more sense for this operation.)